# Can I create a date variable in R for dbGetQuery?

Tags: r, dbi

This is my code:

```
cohort_query <- dbGetQuery(con,'select u.unique_id customer_id,
    o.user_id user_hash,
    "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) first_order,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(\'2021-11-01\') - INTERVAL \'1\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 0
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(\'2021-11-01\') - INTERVAL \'2\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 1
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(\'2021-11-01\') - INTERVAL \'3\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 2
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(\'2021-11-01\') - INTERVAL \'4\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 3
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(\'2021-11-01\') - INTERVAL \'5\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 4
            ELSE 5
        END
    ) "cohort_year",
    min(o.id) as first_order_id
FROM (
        "bj-analytics"."mysql_bj_orders" o
        INNER JOIN "bj-analytics"."mysql_bj_users" u ON (u.user_id = o.user_id)
    )
WHERE (
        (
            (o.connectedorder = false)
            AND (o.status <> \'cancelled\')
        )
        AND (o.status <> \'Cancelled\')
    )
GROUP BY 1,
    2
HAVING (
        "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(\'2021-11-01\') - INTERVAL \'6\' YEAR)
    )
    and "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) < date(\'2021-11-01\')')
```

This all runs fine. Basically, I want to make the 2021-11-01 date a variable, so that I only have to enter it once.
Someone recommended `glue_sql` but I couldn't make it work. I think it's an issue with the double quotation marks and the single marks. I tried to change these to all "" or to all '' but then the query just doesn't run!

I also found that I have to include \'s - again without them doesn't seem to run.

I'm new to R so not too sure how to get around this!

Basically can anyone please help with turning that date into a variable?

Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Never use `paste` or `sprintf` to put "data" into a query, for many reasons (query optimization/caching and accidental sql-injection being the top two), instead use parameter-binding:

```r
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "
  select (case
    when (5 < ?) then 5 
    when (3 < ?) then 3 
    when (1 < ?) then 1 
    else 0 end) as quux",
  params = replicate(n=3, expr=3, simplify = FALSE))
#   quux
# 1    1
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "
  select (case
    when (5 < ?) then 5 
    when (3 < ?) then 3 
    when (1 < ?) then 1 
    else 0 end) as quux",
  params = replicate(n=3, expr=10, simplify = FALSE))
#   quux
# 1    5
```

The `replicate(3,10,F)` is just a programmatic way to do `list(10,10,10)`, they are equivalent here. My use of static comparisons (`5 < ?`) is solely for placeholders, your `min(.)` should work fine.

(FYI, one more benefit of parameter-binding: no need to deal with additional quotes in the query.)

See https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries for more discussions on *safely* using data in the query.

I think that would make your query this:

```r
cohort_query <- dbGetQuery(con, 'select u.unique_id customer_id,
    o.user_id user_hash,
    "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) first_order,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(?) - INTERVAL \'1\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 0
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(?) - INTERVAL \'2\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 1
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(?) - INTERVAL \'3\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 2
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(?) - INTERVAL \'4\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 3
            WHEN (
                "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(?) - INTERVAL \'5\' YEAR)
            ) THEN 4
            ELSE 5
        END
    ) "cohort_year",
    min(o.id) as first_order_id
FROM (
        "bj-analytics"."mysql_bj_orders" o
        INNER JOIN "bj-analytics"."mysql_bj_users" u ON (u.user_id = o.user_id)
    )
WHERE (
        (
            (o.connectedorder = false)
            AND (o.status <> \'cancelled\')
        )
        AND (o.status <> \'Cancelled\')
    )
GROUP BY 1,
    2
HAVING (
        "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) >= (date(?) - INTERVAL \'6\' YEAR)
    )
    and "min"(o.deliveryconfirmeddate) < date(?)'),
  params = replicate(n=7, expr='2021-11-01', simplify=FALSE)
```